# Code can not find specific value from JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, ontime

I using C# to do api calls on software call OnTime by axosoft.

I created three custom fields in the client:

custom_170

custom_171

custom_172

Each field gets added to a section in the JSON call "custom_fields". OnTime provide an their own API wrapper that allows ease of use working with their code.

In the C# code below I'm using get to pull the JSON from "Defects" then I'm looping through looking for defect number 7.

If number 7 is found it will pull 5 values from the JSON Id, Name, custom_170, custom_171, custom_172.

The issue I'm running into is that my program finds Id, Name, custom_170, but the if statement that looks for custom_171 get the value from custom_172 and the last if never seems to be touched (see Results below).

What can I to get the values from custom_171 and custom_172, and get them in the right place?

JSON (snippet)

```
{
    "data": {
        "reported_date": "2014-09-25T04:00:00Z",
        "percent_complete": 100,
        "archived": false,
        "publicly_viewable": false,
        "completion_date": null,
        "due_date": null,
        "description": "",
        "name": "Defect Created from API Explorer 3",
        "notes": "",
        "number": "7",
        "custom_fields": {
            "custom_171": "Work Around Steps",
            "custom_172": "Work Journal",
            "custom_170": "Analysis"
        }
    }
}
```

C# code

```
        var DefectInfo = axosoftClient.Defects.Get();

        int? defectID = 0;
        string defectName = "";
        string defectAnalysis = "";
        string defectWAS = "";
        string defectWJ = "";

        foreach (var defect in DefectInfo.Data)
        {
            if(defect.Id == 7)
            {
                defectID = defect.Id;
                defectName = defect.Name;
                if(defect.CustomFields.ContainsKey("custom_170"))
                {
                    defectAnalysis = (string)defect.CustomFields["custom_170"];
                }
                if(defect.CustomFields.ContainsKey("custom_171"))
                {
                    defectWAS = (string)defect.CustomFields["custom_171"];
                }
                if (defect.CustomFields.ContainsKey("custom_172"))
                {
                    defectWAS = (string)defect.CustomFields["custom_172"];
                }

            } 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Defect ID: {0} Defect Name: {1}\nAnalysis: {2} \nWork Around: {3}\nWork Journal: {4}\n\n", defectID, defectName, defectAnalysis, defectWAS, defectWJ);
```

Results

```
Defect ID: 7 Defect Name: Defect Created from API Explorer 3
Analysis: Analysis
Work Around: Work Journal
Work Journal:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`defectWAS` is assigned twice while `defectWJ` is not assigned new value

You probably meant:

```
if (defect.CustomFields.ContainsKey("custom_172"))
{
    defectWJ = (string)defect.CustomFields["custom_172"];
}
```

Comment: Wow... I've been staring this code for an hour and did not see that. Thanks for the assistance.